# How should I Handle IAM Authentication Token Expiration in Node.js for Memorystore Redis

Tags: node.js, redis-cluster, google-cloud-memorystore

I'm implementing a Node.js service that connects to a Memorystore Redis cluster using IAM authentication, which involves using an access token for the Redis AUTH command.

Considering the hourly expiration of the AUTH token, relying on it solely for authentication proves impractical for continuous service access.

How can I efficiently handle token expiration and refresh in a Node.js application?
Are there recommended practices or libraries for managing the token lifecycle, including automatic refreshing, to maintain uninterrupted access to Memorystore Redis?

I used the standard Redis client configuration to connect to a Memorystore Redis cluster.
due to the IAM authentication token expiring every hour, my service suffered authentication failures and disconnects.

```
createClient({
    socket: {
      host: process.env.REDIS_CLUSTER_HOST,
      port: +process.env.REDIS_CLUSTER_PORT
    },
    password: process.env.REDIS_CLUSTER_PASSWORD
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Memorystore's IAM authentication](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/cluster/about-iam-auth), the access token that you retrieve [expires after 1 hour](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/cluster/about-iam-auth#iam_access_token_time_frame) by default. Alternatively, you can define the access token expiration time when you [generate an access token](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct#create-access).

If you use the REST API, and your system is configured to allow extended token lifetimes, you can create a token with a lifetime longer than the default. Do note that before you are able to use the code in the documentation, you have to set up [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc).

Also, take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types#at-lifetime). You can use REST API's Method: [projects.serviceAccounts.generateAccessToken](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateAccessToken) to create a token with a maximum lifetime of 12 hours.